# Show that $ I = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(2x) + \sin(x) + 3}} < \frac{1}{2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

How to efficiently show that

$$ I = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(2x) + \sin(x) + 3}} < \frac{1}{2} $$

?

What I tried :

$$\sin(2x) + \sin(x) + 3 =
2 \cos(x)\sin(x) + \sin(x) + 3 =(2 \cos(x) + 1)\sin(x) + 3$$

and that is about

$$(2(1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24 - O(x^6) ) + 1)(x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - O(x^7)) + 3$$

and more importantly, it is above

$$(2(1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24 -1/720 ) + 1)(x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 -1/5040) + 3$$

and therefore we compute (in closed form or numerical method)

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{((2(1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24 -1/720 ) + 1)(x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 -1/5040) + 3} $$

what is about $0.24..$

Now including the $\sqrt *$ should be about twice that, what makes about $0.49..$.

(edit : to be more precise : Jensen's inequality gives here $\int \sqrt{f(x)} dx < \sqrt \int f(x) dx$ , so $\sqrt 0.24.. = 0.49... < \frac{1}{2}$ see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality )

But this gets complicated, I want an efficient and convincing method.

But lets continue by truncating further :

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3x + 3}} = \frac{2(\sqrt 2 - 1)}{\sqrt 3}$$

this is about $0.478$, however this requires $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ and is in fact a lower bound, not an upper bound.

I tried a truncated product as well, but also without any simple ways to success.

Then I gave up.

Edit : I explained how I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

and thus the answer of Zarrax is most appealing to me for now.

Comment: Numerically, the result is roughly 0.493284.  So that bound is fairly tight.

Comment: You need to show that the function inside the integration is less than $x/2$...can you continue after this?

Comment: @MarkViola yes I can confirm that value. And there also exists a closed form, however it is not a simple closed form. And that is why I find it so fascinating. There has to be a better way. Or even a best/fastest way.

Comment: @mick My initial thought was to bound the integrand using Taylor's theorem.  But this results in an uper bound of $$I<\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{3+3x-3x^3/2}}\,dx\approx 0.495425804018<0.5$$  However, the antiderivative is also a "mess."

Comment: @MarkViola yeah, I had that idea too. And then I tried a product form. And then I posted it here lol

Comment: @RiverLi And now mick has done so.  Perhaps, old comments that clutter things ought to be deleted, don't you agree?

Comment: Are there easier solutions than the ones below?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon yes I wonder about that.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, I agree. Actually, even if you did not comment to reminder me, I will delete. Yesterday, I just asked some users to delete the old comment when our discussion comes to an end.

Comment: @RiverLi do u have any easy solutions?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon I just found my second solution.

Comment: @RiverLi that is even harder..?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon I think it is simpler. The process is obvious except for the last step $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin 1 + \sin \frac12 + 3}} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}
+ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{\sin 2 + \sin 1 + 3}} < 1/2$ for which we need some calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor's Theorem we find that

$$\frac1{\sqrt{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+3}}\le \frac1{\sqrt 3}-\frac{x}{2\sqrt 3}+\frac{\sqrt 3 x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16\sqrt 3}$$

The proof of this bound is left to the reader.

Then, we have

$$I< \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{\sqrt 3}-\frac{x}{2\sqrt 3}+\frac{\sqrt 3 x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16\sqrt 3}\right)\,dx=\frac{55\sqrt{3}}{192}<\frac12$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Actually, in this case, I'm not sure how you intend for the final integral to be evaluated (when I misread as $x^2$ I could see it working out to an arcsine). I certainly don't notice any simple structure to use to factorise or anything, would you add a comment on this to the answer?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Well, this is one way to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

We use the bound
$$\sqrt{\sin 2x + \sin x + 3} \ge \sqrt{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x - \frac{\sqrt 3}{4}x^2, \quad \forall x \in [0, 1].$$
The proof is given at the end.
(*Note*: The second order Taylor approximation of LHS around zero is $\sqrt{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x - \frac{\sqrt 3}{8}x^2$. We modify the last term to make the inequality.)

Then we have
\begin{align*}
 I &\le \frac{4}{\sqrt 3}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{4 + 2x - x^2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{4}{\sqrt 3}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} + 1 - x} + \frac{1}{x - 1 + \sqrt{5}}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{15}}\left(\ln(\sqrt{5} + 1) - \ln\sqrt{5}\right) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{15}}\left(\ln \sqrt{5} - \ln(\sqrt{5} - 1)\right)\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{15}}\ln\frac{3 + \sqrt 5}{2}\\[6pt]
 &< \frac12.
\end{align*}

*Proof of the bound.*

If $x\in [0, 4/5]$, using the known inequalities $\sin 2x \ge 2x - (2x)^3/6$ and $\sin x \ge x - x^3/6$ for all $x \ge 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{2x - (2x)^3/6 + x - x^3/6 + 3}
\ge \sqrt{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x - \frac{\sqrt 3}{4}x^2$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{3}{16}x^2 (4 - 4x - x^2) \ge 0.$$

If $x\in (4/5, 1]$, using $\sqrt{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x - \frac{\sqrt 3}{4}x^2 
\le \sqrt{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 3}{4}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{\sin 2x + \sin x + 3} \ge \frac54\sqrt{3}$$
or
$$f(x) := \sin 2x + \sin x - \frac{27}{16} \ge 0.$$
Note that $f(x)$ is concave since $f''(x) = -4\sin 2x - \sin x < 0$. Also, $f(4/5) > 0$ and $f(1) > 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $(4/5, 1]$.
We are done.

Answer (score 3):

Use the formula $\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin({a + b \over 2})\cos({a - b \over 2})$ to rewrite your integral as
$$\int_0^1 {dx \over \sqrt{2\sin {3x \over 2}\cos {x \over 2} + 3}}$$
Here $\cos {x \over 2}$ is minimized when $x = 1$, so this is bounded by
$$\int_0^1 {dx \over \sqrt{2\sin {3x \over 2}\cos {1 \over 2} + 3}}$$
By Cauchy-Schwartz or Jensen's inequality this in turn is bounded by
$$\bigg(\int_0^1 {dx \over 2\sin {3x \over 2}\cos {1 \over 2} + 3}\bigg)^{1 \over 2}$$
This integral can be evaluated directly using the formula
$$\int {1 \over a \sin x + b} = 2 {1 \over \sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}{\tan^{-1}\bigg({a + b \tan(x/2)) \over \sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}}\bigg)$$
When you plug things in you end up with something slightly less than ${1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 3):

**My second solution.**

Let $f(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x + \sin x + 3}}$. We claim that $f(x)$ is convex.
Indeed, $g(u) := \frac{1}{\sqrt u}$ is convex and non-increasing on $u > 0$, $h(x) := \sin 2x + \sin x + 3$ is concave on $[0, 1]$, thus $f(x) = g(h(x))$ is convex on $[0, 1]$. (We don't need to calculate $f''(x)$.)

Thus, by Hermite-Hadamard inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_0^{1/2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_{1/2}^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\[6pt]
 &\le (1/2-0)\cdot \frac{f(0)+f(1/2)}{2} + (1-1/2)\cdot \frac{f(1/2)+f(1)}{2}\\[6pt] 
    &=\frac12f(1/2) + \frac14f(0) + \frac14f(1)\\[6pt]
    &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin 1 + \sin \frac12 + 3}} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}
+ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{\sin 2 + \sin 1 + 3}}\\
 &< \frac12.
\end{align*}
(*Remark*: If one doesn't use Hermite-Hadamard inequality directly, one may get the same result by the well-known properties of convex functions.)

Hermite-Hadamard inequality: for convex function $f$,
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \le (b-a)\cdot \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

Comment: Clean and neat, +1!

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks.

Comment: that's harder than the initial solution...

Comment: +1. For those interested, this HH inequality has a Q analogue : https://advancesincontinuousanddiscretemodels.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-020-03163-1#:~:text=(%5B22%5D)-,If%20f%20%3A%20%5B%20a%20%2C%20b%20%5D%20%E2%86%92%20R%20is%20a,(%20b%20)%201%20%2B%20q%20.

Comment: @mick It is interesting.